# Recommended pattern for a queue accessed by multiple threads...what should the worker thread do?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have a queue of objects that is being added to by a thread A. Thread B is removing objects from the queue and processing them. There may be many threads A and many threads B.

I am using a mutex when the queue in being "push"ed to, and also when "front"ed and "pop"ped from as shown in the pseudo-code as below:

Thread A calls this to add to the queue:

```
void Add(object)
{
    mutex->lock();
    queue.push(object);
    mutex->unlock();
}
```

Thread B processes the queue as follows:

```
object GetNextTargetToWorkOn()
{
    object = NULL;

    mutex->lock();
    if (! queue.empty())
    {
        object = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
    }
    mutex->unlock();

    return(object);
}

void DoTheWork(int param)
{
    while(true)
    {
        object structure;

        while( (object = GetNextTargetToWorkOn()) == NULL)
            boost::thread::sleep(100ms); // sleep a very short time

        // do something with the object
    }    
}
```

What bothers me is the while---get object---sleep-if-no-object paradigm. While there are objects to process it is fine. But while the thread is waiting for work there are two problems

a) The while loop is whirling consuming resources
b) the sleep means wasted time is a new object comes in to be processed

Is there a better pattern to achieve the same thing?

Comment: The "pattern" to use is a condition variable.

Comment: .. or a semaphore.....

Comment: Side-note: Don't explicitly call `lock` and `unlock`. C++11 gave you [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) for exception/programmer safe RAII management of `mutex` locking, please use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using spin-waiting, a better design is to use a monitor. Read more on the details on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29).
And a cross-platform solution using std::condition_variable with a good example can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: Yes, the monitor pattern worked very well for me - thank you

Answer (score 0):

> a) The while loop is whirling consuming resources 
>   b) the sleep means wasted time is a new object comes in to be processed

It has been my experience that the sleep you used actually 'fixes' both of these issues.

a) The consuming of resources is a small amount of ram, and **remarkably small** fraction of available cpu cycles.

b) Sleep is **not** a wasted time on the OS's I've worked on.

c) Sleep can affect 'reaction time' (aka latency), but has seldom been an issue (outside of interrupts.)

The time spent in sleep is **likely** to be several orders of magnitude longer than the time spent in this simple loop.  i.e. It is not significant.

---

IMHO - this is an ok implementation of the 'good neighbor' policy of relinquishing the processor as soon as possible.

---

On my desktop, AMD64 Dual Core, Ubuntu 15.04, a semaphore enforced context switch takes ~13 us.

100 ms ==> 100,000 us .. that is 4 orders of magnitude difference, i.e. VERY insignificant.

In the 5 OS's (Linux, vxWorks, OSE, and several other embedded system OS's) I have worked on, sleep (or their equivalent) is the correct way to relinquish the processor, so that it is not blocked from running another thread while the one thread is in sleep.

---

Note: It is feasible that some OS's sleep might not relinquish the processor.  So, you should always confirm.  I've not found one.  Oh, but I admit I have not looked / worked much on Windows.

Comment: On Windows, it takes 5-8us, (on my i7),  to make a thread running by posting a unit to a semaphore that the the thread was waiting on, (given that a core is available).  Windows Sleep() API does what you would expect - execution is removed from the calling thread until the Sleep interval is over, at which point the thread becomes ready again, (and then running when a core is available).  IIRC though, a semaphore post to a waiting thread supplies a temporary priority boost to the waiting thread, Sleep() expiry does not.